Retrieving value in textbox when combobox is selected
I am trying to populate the text in column B when the part number in column A is selected. Combobox5 is retrieving the information in column A and TextBox2 should be populating the description in column B based on the part number selected. The only issue I have is that for example when part number 01368389 is selected, it should retrieve the text in column B2 but it does not. Can someone help guide me as to what I am doing wrong?

The ListBox list index starts at 0.
The formula add (concatenate) the cell reference and the listindex value (ie. B1 & 6 = B16) as text not a number, this cause the incorrect result.
In this example:



A
B
C




25
ListBox List
Excel row


26
A27:A32
First=27


27
ListIndex=0
First+ind=27


28
ListIndex=1
First+ind=28


29
ListIndex=2
First+ind=29


30
ListIndex=3
First+ind=30


31
ListIndex=4
First+ind=31


32
ListIndex=5
First+ind=32



Based on it Index + FirstRow is the corresponding row in the table.
Try this formula:
Me.TextBox2.Text = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & Me.ComboBox5.ListIndex + 2)

It still did not work for me. When I enter the part number in ComboBox5, the description should be displayed next to the part number in column B in TextBox2. I would appreciate the help in understanding what error is in my code.
